# How can I get rails to use pg by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

It's not a huge burden but I would really like to be able to change the default gem-set on my rails apps when I create them so that they're ready for Heroku.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the database with `-d` when running `rails new`:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                              # Default: sqlite3

Description:
    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.
```

So for PostgreSQL this is:

```
rails new myapp -d postgresql
```

To make this the default put `-d postgresql` into `~/.railsrc`

Another option is to change `gem 'sqlite3'` to `gem 'pg'` in your `Gemfile` as suggested in [Getting Started with Rails 3.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

Comment: Thanks. Just for other newbies like me, I had to run 'mate .railsrc' when my default home directory to create the .railsrc file to which I added your suggestion.